# Paste code in R (connected by ssh)

Tags: r, ssh, clipboard

When using R in local I can copy text from a file directly to the console without problems.

However, when I connect by ssh to another machine and use R, I can not paste fairly large text (4000 characters or more). If the R code I am hitting does not contain text strings (between "" or "'") the problem does not occur, but if it contains them, there comes a time when a line like paste0 ("aa", "bb") breaks , arriving only paste0 ("a From that moment on, all the lines are left out ...

Any ideas?

P.D .: I have tested with several machines, all Linux

Comment: Could you send the data as a file instead? (scp) What program is running on the remote host? (What are you pasting into?)

Comment: I could use scp, but what I want is to solve this problem I have years ago, of course while I use other options.
Sorry, I do not quite understand the question. I connect by ssh to a remote machine and I throw R; once I enter, I hit the code there (usually to do tests)